# Adding time dependence on the variables

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, physics

I am trying to add time dependence on the variables. I have used sympy to define the variables (theta and theta_dot). There is no problem when computing the partial derivative but I am having trouble when calculating the total derivative with respect to time.

The equation I am handling is the Euler Lagrange equation.

[image]

I have used sympy

```
diff(L,theta)
```

and

```
diff(L,theta_dot)
```

to find the partial derivatives.

Ideally, I would like to know a good method to integrate the time derivative into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamicsymbols in sympy.

```
list_of_variables=[dynamicsymbols("theta"),dynamicsymbols("theta",1)]

f = diff(diff(i, list_of_variables[1]), 't') - diff(i, list_of_variables[0])
```

Here is a similar post.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014868/euler-lagrange-formalism-with-sympy